# Where does the owner *name* for an S3 bucket/AWS account come from?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This feels like it should be really obvious, but I can't find any clues. I've just started using S3 on AWS. I set up a new free account linked with my Amazon account. When I create a bucket, the name of the owner of the bucket is different from my IAM name, from my AWS account name, and from my Amazon account name. Where does that owner name come from? How can I change/edit it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

S3 actually uses AWS root account user's forum account's nickname in the Owner and Grantee fields. There is a discussion about this [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=395236).

You can change the forum nickname, in order to change what is displayed in S3, [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/username.jspa).

Comment: This is so bizarre, but thanks for the answer. I tried and tried and no matter what my s3 buckets always say 'owner (my old name)'. I changed my name in the forums, and I signed in and out a bunch of times. I tried creating buckets both with root user, and with AIM user. Tried creating buckets from the CLI as well as web interface. Are there any other 'tricks' associated with this metadata? Seems so arbitrary for AWS to do this method of naming.

Comment: My S3 buckets also use the old nickname. When I click on your link, I get this page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqw30.png It asks me to enter a nickname and an email for the forum, like my nickname isn't already set. Being logged in to Amazon.com was not enough, I had to be logged in to AWS management console using the root account. Once I did that, it showed me the correct nickname that is used in S3 buckets. However, after changing it, S3 still shows the same nickname, like @AlexGRice said.

Comment: Same, logged in via root account, changed name, but S3 did not update.

Comment: I have the same problem. The AWS Developer Forum does show the old name, and I can update it there. But S3 still shows the old name when I create a new bucket. This appears to be a bug in S3.

Comment: This accepted answer does not seem to hold true in 2018.  Does anyone else know something that works?

Comment: @Mabyn, it still true as of 2020. If you log in as IAM user, it's not your nickname but  AWS root account user's forum account's nickname.

Comment: @abbr No, it still doesn't work.  I've tried changing the root account's forum nickname and the bucket owner name still does not change (even with new buckets and objects).

Answer (score 1):

AWS is stupid here. According to AWS support, it is your root account's forum account's **initial** nickname. However it is there forever, even later you change your forum account's nickname. AWS is not able to change it.

Comment: This is what I suspected. Can you share a reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

As of 01/02/2023, the display name of S3 bucket owner seems to be the email address name of the root user.

For example, if the root user has the account email address "abcde@xxxxx.com", the display name of the S3 bucket owner will be "abcde".